# Why is Kubernetes (AWS EKS) registering all workers to the Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to know whether this is a default behaviour or something wrong with my setup.

I have 150 workers running on kubernetes.

I made a set of kubernetes workers (10 workers) run only a specific deployment using nodeSelector, I created a service (type=LoadBalancer) for it, when the Load Balancer was created all the 150 workers of Kubernetes were registered to the Load Balancer, while I was expecting to see only this set of workers (10 workers) of this deployment/service.

It behaved the same with `alb-ingress-controller` and `AWS NLB`

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - port: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

and the deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  replicas: 10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: master-api
        image: private/my-app:prod
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 8000Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      nodeSelector:
        role: api
```

I was already labeled 10 workers nodes with the label `role=api`
the 10 run only pods of this deployment, and no other worker is running this service
I also don't have another service or container using port 8080

Comment: Please don't cross-post. This was already posted on [sf], where it is on topic. It should be deleted here.

Answer (score 0):

So ALB controller actually doesn't check your labels etc. It is purely looking at the labels in your subnet. So, if your worker nodes are running inside the subnet with tag `kubernetes.io/role/alb-ingress` or something like that, all your worker nodes from it will be added to the load balancer.

I believe it is part of the auto-discovery thing [docs](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/controller/config/)